# Path entry error in opencv eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to configure opencv in Eclipse Luna by following [this](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/using-opencv-3-0-0-with-eclipse/) method. After editing my project settings Eclipse is showing an error

`Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid project path: Include path not found (/home/opu/workspace/opencvImage/Release/-I/usr/local/include/opencv). opencvImage     pathentry   Path Entry Problem`

How to solve it?

[image: Screenshot]